# Using iterator over a list within the if statement in Python

Tags: python, list, if-statement, filter

I am using a function to read a particular file, which in this case is `options` and do some regex for every line I read. The file I am reading is:

```
EXE_INC = \
    -I$(LIB_SRC)/me/bMesh/lnInclude \
    -I$(LIB_SRC)/mTools/lnInclude \
    -I$(LIB_SRC)/dynamicM/lnInclude
```

My code is

```
def libinclude():
    with open('options', 'r') as options:
    result = []
    for lines in options:
        if 'LIB_SRC' in lines and not 'mTools' in lines:
            lib_src_path = re.search(r'\s*-I\$\(LIB_SRC\)(?P<lpath>\/.*)', lines.strip())
            lib_path = lib_src_path.group(1).split()
            result.append(lib_path[0])
            print result
return (result)
```

Now as you can see, I look for the line that has `mTools` and filter using `not 'mTools' in lines`. However, when I have many such strings how do I filter? Say, for example, I would like to filter the lines that has `mTools` and `dynamicM`. Is it possible to put such strings in a list and then access the elements of that list against `lines` in the `if` statement?

Comment: use `with open('options', 'r').readlines()`

Comment: @latheefitzmeontv How does using readlines help me to filter out the lines? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the built-in function [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all):

```
present = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
absent = ['spam', 'eggs']
for line in options:
    if all(opt in line for opt in present) and all(
           opt not in line for opt in absent):
       ...
```

See also: [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any).

Comment: Thanks @Lev. I was looking for this type of logic. I did look at `any()` and `all()` but I was doing something wrong with the logic within, which wasn't getting the right thing.